# Send JSON Request to my server in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to send JSON request

```
   for (let i = 0; i < this.myLaptopNamesList.length; i++) {
  alert(""+i);
  let LaptopMake1 = 'LaptopMake'+i;
  let LaptopSerial1='LaptopSerial'+i;
  alert(""+LaptopMake1+""+LaptopSerial1)
  alert(""+this.myLaptopNamesList[i].name+""+this.myLaptopNamesList[i].number)
 let  customLaptop: {};

  customLaptop = {
    LaptopMake1: this.myLaptopNamesList[i].name,
    LaptopSerial1: this.myLaptopNamesList[i].number
  };
  this.newCusomLaptop = customLaptop;
}
```

I got laptopMake and LaptopSerial from my for loop. How can I send the request?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share the code you used?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `Http` from `@angular/http`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AppProvider {
constructor(private http: Http) {}

public postRequest(customLaptop: any):Observable<SearchCriteriaObject> {
    let url:string = 'url you want to post to';

    return this.http.post(url, customLaptop)
      .map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }
}
```

inside your component.ts you would call this method and subscribe to the response.

```
import { AppProvider } from 'location of app provider';

export class Component {
    constructor(private provider: AppProvider){}

    this.provider.postRequest(this.customLaptop)
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
            // do something on success
        }, (error: any) => {
            // do something on error
        })
}
```